# refinerycms not run under ruby enterprise edition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu

I'm trying to run a project with installed refinerytcms

```
`root@bas:/work/web# ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-02-18 patchlevel 334) [x86_64-linux], MBARI 0x6770, Ruby Enterprise     Edition 2011.03
root@bas:/work/web# gem -v
1.8.11
root@bas:/work/web# rails -v
Rails 3.1.2
root@bas:/work/web# ruby -e 'puts $:'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby
/usr/local/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8
/usr/local/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux
/usr/local/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux`
```

I get errors

```
root@bas:/work/web# refinerycms tln.kz

/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find activesupport (= 3.0.10) amongst [abstract-1.0.0, actionmailer-3.1.2, actionmailer-3.1.1, actionmailer-3.0.11, actionmailer-3.0.10, actionmailer-3.0.9, actionmailer-3.0.7, actionmailer-3.0.5, actionmailer-3.0.4truncate_html-0.5.1, truncate_html-0.5.0, tzinfo-0.3.31, tzinfo-0.3.29, tzinfo-0.3.27, tzinfo-0.3.25, tzinfo-0.3.24, tzinfo-0.3.23, uglifier-1.1.0, warden-1.1.0, warden-1.0.4, warden-1.0.3, will_paginate-3.0.2, will_paginate-3.0.pre2] (Gem::LoadError)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:761:in `activate_dependencies'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:758:in `each'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:758:in `activate_dependencies'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:742:in `activate'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:764:in `activate_dependencies'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:758:in `each'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:758:in `activate_dependencies'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:742:in `activate'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:764:in `activate_dependencies'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:758:in `each'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:758:in `activate_dependencies'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:742:in `activate'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:764:in `activate_dependencies'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:758:in `each'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:758:in `activate_dependencies'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:742:in `activate'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1211:in `gem'
    from /usr/local/bin/refinerycms:18
`
```

Answer (score 0):

did you run your bundle install?  looks like you're missing a lot of gems and the bundle install should pull the required gems to run.

Comment: project was not created, where can i run "bundle install"

Comment: sorry you have to run bundle update first it seems. here is more details: [refinerycms](http://refinerycms.com/guides/how-to-update-refinery-to-the-latest-stable-version)

Answer (score 0):

The version of Refinery you're using is not compatible with Rails 3.1.2